# "Job seekers" or "job searchers"? American English

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, nouns

I want to describe people who are searching for a job with a noun. I wanted to use "job searchers", but it looks like this noun is not so popular according to Google search.

What is a better name for people searching for a job: Job seekers or job searchers?

P.S. I received the British perspective. What about the American one?

Comment: **Job seekers** is so much more common it's the only one you should use.  *Job searchers* isn't grammatically wrong, but it's so rare it looks weird: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=job+seekers%2Cjob+searchers&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjob%20seekers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjob%20searchers%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, "Job seeker" or "Jobseeker" is the term used by the government for those people who don't have a job and are actively looking for work.  Job seekers are eligible for welfare payments (the Jobseeker's Allowance) and other support.

As is often the case with compound nouns, a person can be seeking a job, but not be a jobseeker.  For example, if you already have a job, but are looking for a new one.

Comment: job seeker is also AmE. Job searcher is sub-standard.

Comment: @James K How do you call a person who already has a job and is seeking a new one?

Comment: @Codewife_101  "A person looking for a new job"